# How do I Add My Domain User Account to the List of Users with Permission to Connect to the SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, windows-authentication

My SQL 2008 R2 Server is configured for Windows authentication, but only my domain administrator account is granted access to connect to the object explorer.

I need to grant my non-administrator domain-user access as well, so I can log in from my local workstation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Connect to the object explorer.  Navigate down to the server > Security > Logins.  Right click and select new login (or add login).  In the new window put your domain account (or group) and grant it what ever rights you want it to have.  If this is just your personal SQL instance on your workstation then just make your account a sysadmin.

Comment: This does not work if the SQL Server is not added to the Domain Controller.

Comment: Yes you have to be on the domain for this to work. But given that the OP stated that his domain admin account had admin rights, the machine being on the domain is a safe assumption.

Comment: Was just adding it for future people.